# Can't create an Angular component that is loading slider-pro images dynamically from a parent component?

Tags: angular

I am for 3 days to create a simple slider-pro Angular component that is receiving an array with image paths (URLs), without success so far.

slider.component.html

```
        <div id="slider-pro"></div>
```

slider.component.ts

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.css']
})
export class SliderComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() images: string[] = [];

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.images && this.images.length > 0) {
      this.initializeSlider(this.images);
    }
  }

  private initializeSlider(images: string[]): void {
    jQuery('#slider-pro').sliderPro({
      width: '100%',
      height: 500,
      fade: true,
      arrows: true,
      buttons: false,
      fullScreen: true,
      smallSize: 500,
      startSlide: 0,
      mediumSize: 1000,
      largeSize: 3000,
      thumbnailArrows: true,
      autoplay: false,
      init: () => {
        const slidesContainer = jQuery('#slider-pro');
  
        for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
          const slideIndex = i + 1;
          const slide = `<div class="sp-slide"><div class="sp-image-container" style="width: 960px; height: 500px;"><img class="sp-image" 
          data-default="${images[i]}" 
          data-retina="${images[i]}" 
          data-large="${images[i]}" 
          data-medium="${images[i]}" 
          data-small="${images[i]}" 
          src="${images[i]}" 
          /></div></div>`;
          slidesContainer.append(`<div class="sp-slides" style="transform: translate3d(-3880px, 0px, 0px);">`);
          slidesContainer.append(slide);
          slidesContainer.append(`</div>`);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

in the parrent component I have:

```
<div *ngIf="hotelImages && hotelImages.length > 0">
    <app-slider [images]="hotelImages"></app-slider>
</div>
```

the slider-pro package is added with

```
npm install slider-pro
```

the path to the css and js files is correct, because I can see the it in dev tools.
This code is generating div nodes with sp-slide and other required divs, but in wrong order.

I was able to generate HTML containing the required div nodes, but in wrong order. I tried every many options, but I can't make it work.